# Knitting pdf document with papaja in R

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, papaja

How do I get rid of the row Numbers in the PDF the Knitr function creates when I use papaja package in R?

Screenshot of PDF wit row numbers

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [noted](https://crsh.github.io/papaja_man/r-markdown-components.html#rendering-options) in the `papaja`-manual, you can toggle line numbers via the YAML front matter parameter `linenumbers`:

```
linenumbers: no
```